# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int[]>' to 'int[][]'

Tags: c#, .net

I want to reverse some chars but I get the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int[]>`' to 'int[][]'.

Below is code for reference.

```
private void tp(int[][] cd = null,int offset = 0)
    {
        if (cd == null) return;
        cd = cd.Reverse();
        /*rest of code...*/
    }
```

Comment: @JohnWu: Your comment is absolutely not right. Your comment might be right for `int[,]` (I've not checked) but it is certainly not true for `int[][]` as can be simply tested.

Comment: I've added the c# tag to the question since your code looks like that's the language you are using. Language tags are helpful to make sure the right people look at your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Reverse` will return an `IEnumerable<T>`, in this case an `IEnumerable<int[]>` as the error message suggests. To get to an `int[][]` all you need to do is call `ToArray()` on the result of the reverse. That is:

```
cd = cd.Reverse().ToArray();
```